# Python Pandas: how to update a csv file from another csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas

We have two CSV files: `a.csv` and `b.csv`.

`a.csv` has tree columns: *label*, *item1*, *item2*. `b.csv` has two columns: *item1*, *item2*. If *item1* and *item2* in `a.csv` also occurr in `b.csv`, that's `a.csv` and `b.csv` have same *item1* and *item2*, the value of label in `a.csv` should be **1** instead. How to use pandas to deal?

---

For example:

**a.csv:**

```
label    item1     item2
 0         123       35
 0         342       721
 0         876       243
```

**b.csv:**

```
item1     item2
 12        35
 32        721
 876       243
```

**result.csv:**

```
label    item1     item2
 0         123       35
 0         342       721
 1         876       243
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("~/train_dataset.csv", names=['label', 'user_id', 'item_id', 'behavior_type', 'user_geohash', 'item_category', 'time','sales'], parse_dates=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv(~/train_user.csv", names=['user_id', 'item_id', 'behavior_type', 'user_geohash', 'item_category', 'time', 'sales'], parse_dates=True)
df1.loc[(df1['user_id'] == df2['user_id'])& (df1['item_id'] == df2['item_id']), 'label'] = 1
```

Comment: Do the items have to be in the same row in both `csv` files, or can a given row in `a.csv` appear anywhere in `b.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `loc` and a boolean condition to mask your df (here representing a.csv) and set the label to 1 if that condition is met:

```
In [18]:

df.loc[(df['item1'] == df1['item1'])& (df['item2'] == df1['item2']), 'label'] = 1
df
Out[18]:
   label  item1  item2
0      0    123     35
1      0    342    721
2      1    876    243
```

If you want to set all row values you could use `np.where`:

```
In [19]:

np.where((df['item1'] == df1['item1'])& (df['item2'] == df1['item2']), 1, 0)
Out[19]:
array([0, 0, 1])
In [20]:

df['label'] = np.where((df['item1'] == df1['item1'])& (df['item2'] == df1['item2']), 1, 0)
df
Out[20]:
   label  item1  item2
0      0    123     35
1      0    342    721
2      1    876    243
```