# Compare 2 csv files and update columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have 2 csv files with 2 rows 3 columns (id, name, value) that I want to compare. If there's a new row added to one of the files, the other one is updated as well. Likewise, if a value in one of the column changes the other file is updated.

Here's what I tried

```
a = '/path/to/file'
b = 'path/to/file'

with open(a, 'r') as f1, open(b, 'r') as f2:
    file1 = csv.DictReader(f1)
    file2 = csv.DictReader(f2)

    for row_new in file2:
        for row_old in file1:
            if row_new['id'] == row_old['id']:
                for k1, v1 in row_new.items():
                    for k, v in row_old.items():
                        if row_old[k1] == row_new[k]:
                            if v1 != v:
                                print(f'updated value for col {k}')
                                v1 = v
                            else:
                                print('Nothing to update')
            else:
                print(f'create row {row_new["id"]}')
```

I noticed that the iteration takes place only once. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: When you inspected/printed values and/or conditions at various points in your program was there an obvious place where it was misbehaving? If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Or the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that the iteration takes place only once...?

The inner loop is probably reaching the end of the file before the outer loop has a chance to *make* its next iteration. Try moving the file object's pointer back to the beginning after the inner loop stops.

```
with open(a, 'r') as f1, open(b, 'r') as f2:
    ...
    for row_new in file2:
        for row_old in file1:
            if row_new['id'] == row_old['id']:
                ...
            else:
                print(f'create row {row_new["id"]}')
        f1.seek(0)
```

---

Some would say that the nested for loops is what you are doing wrong. Here are some SO questions/answers to consider.

[python update a column value of a csv file according to another csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407427/python-update-a-column-value-of-a-csv-file-according-to-another-csv-file)
[Python Pandas: how to update a csv file from another csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607967/python-pandas-how-to-update-a-csv-file-from-another-csv-file)
search `python csv update one csv file based on another site:stackoverflow.com`

Basically you should try to just read each file once and use data types that allow for *fast* membership testing like sets or dicts.

Your DictReaders will give you an `{'id':x,'name':y,'value':z}` dict for each row - causing you to use nested for loops to compare all the rows from one file to each row in the other.  You could create a single dictionary using the `id` column for the keys and the dictionary values could be lists - `{id:[name,value],id:[name,value],...}` which may make the processing easier.

---

You also opened both your files for reading, `open(...,'r')`, so you'll probably find your files unchanged after you fix other things.

Comment: I run into an error `AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'seek'`

Comment: @twingo `f1` is a file object, not a DictReader.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The error is `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: Fixed it. It was an indentation issue. Thank you very much !